# How do you make sense of the phrase "celle du chef de l’Etat"?

Tags: sens, pronoms

Another question on the [recent Le Monde article](http://www.lemonde.fr/proche-orient/article/2017/11/18/liban-l-ex-premier-ministre-saad-hariri-recu-a-l-elysee-par-emmanuel-macron_5216992_3218.html) about Lebanon. How would you translate the phrase, *qui devait préparer celle du chef de l’Etat désireux de jouer les médiateurs*? I understand it to mean "who had to prepare the head of state wishing to play the mediators", but I think my translation is a little off. I suppose *celle du chef de l’Etat* could mean "this head of state", but then I'm not sure why the partitive article *du* would separate *celle* and *chef*.

> Dans ce climat, la visite à Téhéran de M. Le Drian, qui devait préparer celle du chef de l’Etat désireux de jouer les médiateurs sur l’accord sur le nucléaire menacé par l’administration de Donald Trump, est renvoyée à des jours meilleurs.
>
> In this climate, the visit to Tehran of Mr. Le Drian, who had to prepare ?? the head of state wishing of playing the mediators on the nuclear accord threatened by the administration of Donald Trump, is referred to better days ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "celle" is "la visite". Mr Le Drian's (Foreign affairs minister) visit is to prepare the visit of the President.